# Need Ideas for Game

Tags: game-design, 3d, java

I've been through a year of programming and have the tools to create a cool, simple 3d game using Java.

The biggest problem I have is ideas. When you have no idea how programming works, you want to create extravagant games and then you realize it doesn't work that way.

I just need a simple game to create. I don't have many models (sphere or block guy) to work with, just a 3d environment my professor created. I can also create a very limited multiplayer aspect (leaderboard, perhaps a 2 player co-op).

So please, throw out some ideas! Or allow me to join your team as an intern. :D

Comment: I've considered doing something like this a few times, but every time I've come to the same conclusion: this is not the place for this kind of a request.  If you have a technical question, this is the place to go to solve those pesky bugs.  But free handouts of game ideas is not the intended purpose of this Stack Exchange.  Anyone is welcome to challenge this allegation, but I believe that you should remove this 'request'.

Comment: @Grimless: I don't think it's a big deal. If people have some ideas they wouldn't mind sharing, then they are free to do so. If not, then that's just fine. I'm not looking for the "idea of the decade" type stuff and that should be known if I'm asking on a public forum.

Comment: True enough.  I simply felt that keeping the site more oriented towards solving development issues over asking others for game ideas was important to me.  Certainly, if anyone is willing to answer your question with game ideas, that is up to them.

Comment: @Grimless indeed, i agree with you.

Comment: @Grimless: How about this for a development issue: lacking ideas? How do I come up with my own!

Comment: Now, see, that is a much better question!  THAT is something the game dev community should be able to help you with.  That question is open enough that it encourages you to work for a real answer with guidance from the community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start small.  Clone pong, breakout, or tetris. Or make a simple game where you explore an island (Myst, anyone?)  If you want a challenge, make an FPS, or a on rail shooter game.  If you want to do something really fun and crazy, make a racing game where you can make the car better not by buying a new engine or upgrading the car, but by adding lightning bolts and flame decals.

Or make a game from your favourite genre (favourite genre may vary, fans of MMOs or Dwarf Fortress may go insane trying to recreate their favourite genre)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of making a shooter/explorer type game, where enemies drop new weapons and armor and such. I'm going to work out on this idea a bit more and the implementation of it.

Comment: I dont think that that whole "start small" thinq is that great at all as everybody says. I made 3D tanks in opengl as first graphics project, do something on which you can really learn. Not something super easy...

Comment: @notabene — The idea is to get used to the steps of game development by recreating classic titles.  This approach lets one understand how all of the components come together to create a game and get a feel of the flow.  If the OP is comfortable with these things, then they should move on to meatier fare, such as creating their own simple game.

Comment: There's a few reasons to start small.  Part of it is to learn more about the tools you're using, part is because a large game will probably result in burnout before you're done, and part is because tons of people who've never made games want to make the next WoW right away.  That said, 'start small' doesn't always mean "make pong", it just means "don't try to make a AAA game as your first project"

Comment: +1 Cloning with deviation from the original design where its convenient or just dawns on you is a good way to go.

Comment: @notabene: Not to rain on your parade but 3D tanks in OpenGL is "start small".

Comment: @Ranieri ... agreed! :) just don't know why everybody points to the making PONG or something.

Comment: @notabene Mostly because pong, tetris, breakout, and similar games are ones everyone has played at some point, and everyone can make, no matter what their skill level is.  It's pretty much the lowest common denominator.  In other words: it's like teaching someone addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division before telling them to learn calculus (or at least, make sure they know the basics of maths before going on to learn advanced stuff).

Comment: Dwarf Fortress fans (myself included) are already insane.

Answer (score 2):

Getting an internship is the best what you can do in your case. Enthusiasm (and you have it) is one of the biggest values for getting one. It will help you grow professionally and personally as well. And last thing to say, if there is no company offering internships, just write them and tell them about you and your skills and how much you are interested in game programming and see what happens. It should work.

Comment: Meh, I'm not too serious about looking for professional interns. Even helping on a small indie team would be cool. I'm a math major so my interests are not purely in game dev or even programming.

Comment: I think @notabene means to say "internship", and not "intern". I.e. Suggesting you take on a role as an intern.

Comment: @NickWiggill Yeah, that is what i wanted to say, thank you.